# Get the square root of an integer in Haskell

Tags: haskell, int

I have a simple function, which is to get the 
hypotenuse of a pythagorean triangle, but for the type of Int.

Here is my code:

```
hypotenuse :: Int -> Int -> Int
hypotenuse a b = sqrt(a*a + b*b)
```

I need to round up the result.

For example: `hypotenuse 500 0   --result:500 :: Int`
`hypotenuse 500 30   --result:501 :: Int`

Comment: @FrownyFrog That should have been an answer. Either way, the question has been asked already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without outright stating the solution, here are some functions you may find handy:

- [`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=fromIntegral);
- [`sqrt :: (Floating a) => a -> a`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=sqrt);
- [`floor, ceiling :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28Floating+a%2C+Integral+b%29+%3D%3E+a+-%3E+b).

The details of your `hypotenuse` function are up to you, so I will leave the implementation to your discretion.